# 2 SFMC Business Units Connected to 1 Sales Cloud Org

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, sales-cloud, sfmc-business-unit, veeva

We are exploring the possibility of having 2 separate business units in one Enterprise 2.0 SFMC account connected to 1 Sales Cloud org via the MCC connector. Is that possible? We don't have issues with having a separate API user for both connections, and the MCC is already up and running, establishing 1-to-1 connections between various SFMC BUs and Sales Cloud orgs.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve had these cases before. We activated the multi org and then connected  two BU to the same Salesforce Org using the same API user. And another org, we connected to a sandbox. Maybe you should think about the functionality of the Multi-Org. Be careful, if you enable it, you can't disabled later.